# How to set the name of a standard or the name of a standard component?

Tags: fonts, nomenclature

Sometimes I am using names of standards, such as "DIN 103". Typing the name in plain text can make it look ugly. Do you have any advice or experience? Can you recommend a generic way that makes it look good? Can you recommend a particular LaTeX standard font?

So far, I have been only adjusting spaces: `DIN\,EN\,13001-3` However, sometimes the numbers are smaller than the capital letters.

*Related question:* Do you have recommendations for setting names of standard components, e.g. "Tr110x12"? So far, I am using `Tr\,110x12` but it sometimes looks cramped.

---

Edit: For now, I have decided to use

```
\newcommand{\std}[1]{{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\footnotesize\textbf{#1}}}%
...
\std{DIN\,103}
```

I have compiled this solution from the answers in this thread and other sources. I like it because of the following reasons:

- The standard name looks different, but it does not "stick out" too much.
- Numbers and letters have the same height.
- It is well readable.

However, the font face is not a standard font (e.g. ISO 3098). And the solution does not look good in every context. Maybe there will arrive more ideas or answers in this thread over time.

Comment: What do you mean by ugly? Have you tried `small caps`? `\textsc{...}`. Small caps are meant to used when a lot of capital letters appear cosecutively and you don't want them to *stick out*.

Comment: Ugly means, among other things, that letters and numbers do not have the same height. The font face should be a sans serif font. The appearance should indicate, that "DIN" and "103" belong together and form a unit.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you at all?  If so it is customary to at least upvote them, and perhaps pick one for as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps)

> Small caps are often used for sections of text that is all uppercase;
>   this makes the run of capital letters seem less jarring to the reader.

Similarly for numbers see [Old style figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
Sometimes I am using names of standards, such as DIN 103.
Typing the name in plain text can make it look ugly.
Do you have any advice or experience?
Can you recommend a generic way that makes DIN EN 13001-3 look good?
Can you recommend a particular LaTeX standard font?
So far, I have been only adjusting spaces: DIN EN 13001-3
However, sometimes the numbers are smaller than the capital letters.
Related question: Do you have recommendations for setting names
of standard components, e.g. TR110x12?
So far, I am using Tr 110x12 but it sometimes looks cramped.

\bigskip
Sometimes I am using names of standards, such as \textsc{din 103}.
Typing the name in plain text can make it look ugly.
Do you have any advice or experience?
Can you recommend a generic way that makes \textsc{din en 13001-3} look good?
Can you recommend a particular \textsc{latex} standard font?
So far, I have been only adjusting spaces: \textsc{din en 13001-3}
However, sometimes the numbers are smaller than the capital letters.
Related question: Do you have recommendations for setting names
of standard components, e.g. \textsc{tr 110x12}?
So far, I am using \textsc{tr 110x12} but it sometimes looks cramped.
\end{document}
```

[image: small caps for running capital letters]

Comment: Good idea, but smallcaps don't work with my font. Based on your idea, I am suggesting: ```\newcommand{\std}[1]{{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\footnotesize\textbf{#1}}}%``` And then I use ```\std{DIN\,103}```. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newfontfamily\csa{Dekar}

\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
%   
    \begingroup\csa\footnotesize\textls[130]{#1}%
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}

    Hello Kitty \abc{DIN  103} by Sanrio.

\end{document}
```

And related, see this wonderful answer: [*Grouping and undefined control sequence error*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309641/90087)

Comment: I like the approach, but the fontspec package requires xelatex or lualatex. At least that's what the error message says when compiling with latex or pdflatex.

Comment: True, but lualatex is basically a pdflatex that understands the lua programming language.