# Grouping and undefined control sequence error

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fontspec, grouping

I was trying to figure out an answer to another question, which required a change of font and size in the middle of a sentence. So I tried to use a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to isolate the change of font and size.  The result is what I was looking for, but it is nonetheless throwing the `undefined control sequence` error.  What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newfontfamily\csa{Dekar}

\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
    \begingroup\csa\footnotesize\textls[130]{#1}%
    \endgroup\normalfont\normalfontsize
}

\begin{document}

    Hello Kitty \abc{DIN  103} by Sanrio.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the question I was considering: [*How to set the name of a standard or the name of a standard component?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299139/90087)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\abc ...{#1}\endgroup \normalfont \normalfontsize 

l.14     Hello Kitty \abc{DIN  103}
                                  by Sanrio.
```

that means the undefined control sequence is `\normalfontsize`.

On the other hand, you ***don't*** need to restore the font and its size, because the group already limits the scope.

I guess the Dekar font is quite big; you can avoid setting a size by loading it at some scale factor. For instance

```
\newfontfamily{\csa}{Dekar}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

and the definition can become

```
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
   {\csa\textls[130]{#1}}%
}
```

Instead of `MatchUppercase` you can specify a factor, such as `0.75`; experiment in order to find the desired magnification.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, much obliged.

Comment: I guess making up your own, mythical, slightly different than actual, control sequences is not exactly "best practice".  Special thanks for being patient with that.